# Iterating through Php $_POST with many variables appended by numeral

Tags: php, mysql, post

So i was wondering how to get the variables from $_POST in php when i set the names of the data to date, start, end with a numeral denoting what number date and start and end they where. For creating the varaibles using forms, it works fine creating the variables, the problem is when accessing them i get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

my code:

```
<?php
$club=$_POST['club'];
$name=$_POST['event'];
$text=$_POST['descript'];

$num=$_POST['quantity'];
$user=$_POST['user'];

$flag=$_POST['flag'];

require_once("conf.inc.php");

$host=$CFG->dbHost;
$userDB=$CFG->dbUser;
$pword=$CFG->dbPassword;
$db=$CFG->dbDatabase;

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $userDB, $pword, $db);
$mysqli->connect($host, $userDB, $pword, $db);
if(!isset($flag)) {
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO fi_events VALUES $name, $text, $club");
    $eventResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT ID FROM fi_events WHERE Name=$name, FlavourText=$text, ClubID=$club");
    while(list($event) = $eventResult->fetch_row()) {
        $ID = $event;
    }
}
else {
    $eventID = $_POST['eventID'];
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO fi_slots VALUES $eventID, $_POST['slots$i'], 0, $_POST['date$i'], $_POST['start$i'], $_POST['end$i']");
    }
    echo "SLOT CREATION SUCCESSFUL!";
    echo "<form action='viewEvent.php' enctype='text/plain' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='eventID' name='eventID' value= '$ID' />
        <input type='hidden' id='user' name='user' value= '$user' />
        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='View Your Event'>
        </form>";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Make Slots</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(!isset($flag)){
    echo ("<form action='makeSlots.php' method='post'>");
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='quantity' name='quantity' value= '$num' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='flag' name='flag' value= '1' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='eventID' name='eventID' value= '$ID' />"
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='user' name='user' value= '$user' />"
    for ($i=0; $i<$num;$i++){
        echo ("Date:&nbsp; <input type='date' id='date$i' name='date$i' />
        <br/>");
        echo ("Time Begin:&nbsp; <input type='text' id='start$i' name='start$i' />
        <br/>");
        echo ("Time End:&nbsp; <input type='text' id='end$i' name='end$i' />
        <br/>");
        echo ("Total Slots:&nbsp; <input type='text' id='slots$i' name='slots$i' />
        <br/>");
    }
    echo ("<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Enter' />");
    echo("</form>");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by $_POST you get value witch is posted are you sure you are posting slots1 ,slots2...slots$num ans also date. ..?

Comment: Which line is the syntax error being reported for?

Comment: You're using mysqli. One of the main reasons to switch from mysql to mysqli is to use prepared statements. So why are you interpolating strings instead of doing that? Switch to prepared statements with placeholders and your problem will go away, and you'll have safer code as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to use concatenation for this one:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO fi_slots VALUES $eventID," . $_POST["slots$i"] . ",...");
```

Comment: Or he could use `$_POST["slots$i"]`. Variable are interpolated inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

Comment: its isnt a problem ..its in double quote ..i suspect problem might be whole $_POST[]

Comment: That's an excellent point.  I thought it might be an issue interpreting the variable two strings deep.  I haven't tried it myself, just seemed like it could be the culprit.

Comment: The problem is that he's already inside a big double-quoted string, so he shouldn't put single quotes inside `$_POST[...]`. But the real solution is to use prepared statements, since he's using mysqli.

Comment: @Barmar i agree with prepared statements...but as far as i tried its not an error

Comment: @Barmar the single quotes are necessary when evaluating the concatenation, as described in my answer.

Comment: @Jack I know, I was just explaining why the OP's code was getting a syntax error. It was the combination of single quotes _inside_ double quotes.

Comment: @Barmar Wrong, it was the missing curly braces around the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be this:

```
"{$_POST['slot' . $i]}"
```

The curly braces unambiguously delineate the expression, so the compiler won't complain and it performs the concatenation inside it.

**Important**

Doing this is not recommended due to sql injection risk and a prepared statement is the way to go:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO fi_slots VALUES (?, ?, 0, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['slots' . $i]);
// etc.
$stmt->execute();
```